# Appending image attributes to certain images meeting criteria using javascript

Tags: javascript

I would like to append the attribute ( nopin = "nopin" ) to the image tags within my page that meet certain criteria using Javascript.  Is that possible?

For example, I have a gallery that uses thumbnails and full size images.  I want to add the tag to any images with a height less than 100px.  The nopin= "nopin" attribute makes it the image not show up when the Pinterest pin-it button is used.

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Yes, that's possible. We'll happily help you fix your code if you fail trying to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("img").each(function () {
        if ($(this).height() < 100) {
            $(this).attr("nopin", "nopin");
        }
    });
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Rg6RM/1/

Comment: Wow that was fast!  Okay so for a guy like me who doesn't know all of this stuff.  Can I just copy and paste that into my site?  My wordpress site has a custom code section that will add it in-between the script tags.  Or do I have to replace some of that code with something specific to my site?

Comment: Okay, I changed the 100px dimension to 110 in the above example and added it to the custom javascript section.  It looks like it added it here... <script src='http://www.marc-photography.net/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.8.3'></script>    but It doesn't seem to be doing what I want it to on my page at www.marc-photography.net/posts/  .  Try clicking on the Pinterest button to see what I mean.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that it was in this js file <script src="http://www.marc-photography.net/wp-content/uploads/p4/static/1363639793_script.js"></script>

Comment: I tried visiting your blog, but it looks like something's stopping the CSS and the javascript from loading (screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/Dml7AtX.png). Try resolving the loading problem and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Thats odd.  It loads fine for me. http://i.imgur.com/LkGrAJ9.png?1

Comment: Well that is strange... Could you see if it works if you're logged out / in incognito mode?

Comment: yup,  I logged out and tried in incognito mode. I just deactivated W3 Total Cache.  Maybe that will change something for you.

Comment: Yeah, that lets it load for me, but it still looks like the script isn't getting run. Maybe take a look at http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Javascript for more help.

Comment: Okay, I will do some digging around to see why it isn't getting run.  Thanks for the code anyway!

Comment: Can you tell me if these errors mean anything to you?  I tried a different plugin to insert the JS.  http://i.imgur.com/wZeIqqb.png

Comment: Try checking "Load Also jQuery", since it's saying $, the jQuery function, isn't defined.

Comment: No luck trying that :-(

Comment: I got it!  I just had to replace all of the $ symbols with the word jQuery.  Works perfectly!  Not sure why, but it did